# Github desktop put subfolder in specific location

Tags: github

I am working on a minecraft datapack. I have a github repo that I am using. It contains 3 files:

- the license
- readme.Md
- a folder which is the datapack

The datapack folder needs to be located at `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\saves\datapacktesting\datapacks`
However I need to keep the license and the read me somewhere else on my computer, outside of this folder. Is there a way I can do this while still being able to commit and publish changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store some folders of a Git repository outside of the repository working tree.  You have two options:

- Add a script to copy the data into the directory you want.
- Use a symbolic link in the location you want your data to be pointing to your repository.

Note that symbolic links, while the logical choice, require administrator privileges on Windows unless you've enabled Developer Mode.